# Bootstrap, link to tab AND add class "active" to tab li without extra JS

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using tabs in Bootstrap 3, I'm using the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute on my `ul.nav > li > a` elements to allow auto-handling of tabbing without writing **extra** JS.

Now, I want to add similar `href` and `data-toggle` attributes to a button and accomplish the same thing (in this case, go to the next step in a payment process).

This accomplishes revealing the desired `tab-pane`, but I **also** want to add `.active` to the `li` element related to said `tab-pane` **without** writing extra JS, is this possible?

I can't seem to find a way in the Bootstrap docs.

Comment: ...this is the default behavior isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's default. In my tabs I have .active on load the current pane and the current related nav item, when another tab is clicked then it gets the .active class. You can look at the docs and see a demo: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs